# Get MySQL table columns using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

How would I get inside of a custom model the columns for a specific MySQL table using Eloquent in Laravel

I was trying `DB::query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table)` but without any success

Comment: Do you get an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: does not return any result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are using is not Eloquent, but raw database queries.

RAW queries:

```
$table = 'your_table';
$columns = DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ". $table);
```

Comment: thanks for the update but unfortunately  I do not get any expected I use it like MyModel::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ". $table);

Comment: OK, that is Eloquent! The answer works for me, but it might not work with Eloquent.

Comment: how do I refactor the method to use in this case raw query

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Eloquent. This is for RAW queries. DB:: is RAW queries.

Comment: okay thanks again to use RAW queries is needed to use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB; in model

Comment: You're welcome! By trying to answer questions I'm learning more and more too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no Eloquent function for this as it is considered out of its scope. I'd just do the following:

```
DB::select('show columns from '.(new MyModel)->getTable());
```

Comment: So it means that I can not handle dynamic tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the columns of your table as a collection where each column is represented as an object. You can even use your model.

Use in You code

```
$columns = MyModel::describe();
```

Add a static method to the model

```
/**
 * Retrieve a collection of sAttributeValue table columns with their corresponding metadata.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public static function describe()
{
    $collection = collect([]);
    $columns = DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".DB::getTablePrefix().MyModel::query()->from);
    if ($columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if ($column) {
                $item = new \stdClass();
                foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
                    $item->{strtolower($key)} = $value;
                }
                $collection->put($item->field, $item);
            }
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Result

```
1 Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1295 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    "id" => {#1300 ▼
      +"field": "id"
      +"type": "bigint unsigned"
      +"null": "NO"
      +"key": "PRI"
      +"default": null
      +"extra": "auto_increment"
    }
    "attribute" => {#1294 ▶}
    "position" => {#1304 ▶}
    "alias" => {#1305 ▶}
    "base" => {#1307 ▶}
    "created_at" => {#1308 ▶}
    "updated_at" => {#1309 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```